# jquery scroll strange skipping bug

Tags: jquery, scroll, behavior

I have a jquery script for scrolling through a highlighted words which can be searched in inserting a word in input. Everything is working but in some strange way. I've set up that #demo-container is animated in script so when you enter a data and you click next, his scrolls moves to next data. But it'seems that something is wrong with script...
First time when you hit next it gets you to the highlighted data but second time, instead of scroll to next word, it moves a little bit backwards and third time it skips second word and moves to third...

I don't know what is problem, here is situation in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/UF7VJ/

html (without a bigger part of text):

```
<div class="dock">
<input type="text" class="span3" id="field1" name="field1" value="term1 term2 term3 term4">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" id="prev1" href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-up icon-white"> </i></a> 
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" id="next1" href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-down icon-white"></i></a>
</div>

<div id="outer">    
<div id="demo-container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dapibus aliquam elementum. 
Nam adipiscing rhoncus consequat. Nam sed dolor ac risus sodales auctor id sit amet quam. 
Aliquam posuere enim ipsum. Aliquam malesuada erat et lectus venenatis, eu ultricies sapien 
convallis. Morbi eu vestibulum leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam neque augue, placerat in dignissim non, faucibus id sapien. Sed 
vitae ligula venenatis, blandit orci in, hendrerit ipsum. In nec sem in metus hendrerit sodales.
 Cras at lectus id elit orn
</div>
</div>
```

script:

```
    // disable highlighting if empty
    if (searchTerm) {
        var terms = searchTerm.split(/\s+/);
        $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
            // highlight the new term
            term = term.trim();
            if (term != "") $('#demo-container').highlight(term, 'highlight1');
        });

    }
}).triggerHandler('change');

});

/**  scroll to element function **/

function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
    time = typeof (time) != 'undefined' ? time : 500;
    verticalOffset = typeof (verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
    element = $(selector);
    offset = element.offset();
    offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
    $('#demo-container').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, time);
}

/**document ready**/
$(document).ready(function () {
    count = 0;
    var max_length = $('.highlight1').length;
    /* scroll to 150px before .highlight with animation time of 400ms */
    $('#next1').click(function (e) {
        if (count < max_length) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 1;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        scrollToElement('.highlight1:nth-child(' + count + ')', 400, -150);
    });

    $('#prev1').click(function (e) {
        if (count > 1) {
            count--;
        } else {
            count = max_length;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        scrollToElement('.highlight1:nth-child(' + count + ')', 400, -150);
    })
});
```

css:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

#outer{
width:500px;
height:300px;
padding-top:50px;
 }
#demo-container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
 overflow:auto;
}

.dock{
position:fixed;
background:#FFFFFF;    
}

.highlight1 {
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
/* FF1+ */
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
/* Saf3-4 */
border-radius: 5px;
/* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
/* FF3.5+ */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
/* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
/* Opera 10.5+, IE 9.0 */
}

.highlight1{
background-color: #fff34d;
}

.highlight1 {
padding:1px 4px;
margin:0 -4px;
}
```

You can edit my jsfiddle freely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add current scroll offset when you update your scroll level.

`offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset + $('#demo-container').scrollTop();`

http://jsfiddle.net/UF7VJ/1/